# Anki: A LOT of "unseen" cards, is all well?

Tags: anki, hebrew

I am a pretty heavy user of anki (1-2 hours/day), and am confused by a statistic and a behavior.

fwiw, I use the templates from Gabriel Wyner/Fluent Forever.

OK, here is the question: What is the "unseen" card count in statistics?

I understand it to be the number of cards I have created but have never seen.

I do think there are a lot of these (I currently create 15-50 cards a day).

I am confused because I think there are cards from a week ago that I have not yet seen, but when I add new cards, I often see them right away.

How do I understand this more fully?

(Apologies, I flipped Anki into Hebrew mode, but it is pretty understandable)

[image]

Comment: I think you might be overrelying on Anki but I would need a bit more information to give appropriate advice. (1) What is your learning goal? (E.g. just reading skills?) (2) What do your cards look like? (Just translation? If yes, in which direction? Or do you create cards only in the way recommended by Wyner?) (3) Do you create cards based on learning materials you are using or do you also use Wyner's lists? (4) Did you set Anki to display cards in the order you created them or in random order?

Comment: @Tsundoku Over rely on Anki?  Not possible ! Anki rocks. Use it, or waste time, that is the choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All is well.

I am creating a lot of cards, and the template I use creates three cards for each card I create (forward and backward, with picture, with spelling quiz).

So I am simply not keeping up with the number of cards I am creating. I am considering upping the new cards/day setting...

Anki is working by design!